# CA 1822 WEB api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the .NET WebAPI for creating RESTful services. However, I'm getting the following warning when running the code analysis:

> > CA1822 : Microsoft.Performance : The 'this' parameter (or 'Me' in Visual Basic) of 'LoginController.Post(Credential)' is never used. Mark the member as static (or Shared in Visual Basic) or use 'this'/'Me' in the method body or at least one property accessor, if appropriate. C:\Workspace\Services\SriLankan.Mobility.Services\Controllers\LoginController.cs

Is there anyway to avoid this? I can't just make the POST method static, because then the framework is unable to map the request.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you see is a recommendation to change your method to be static. Is that applicable. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices

1. Correct the code - make sure it does not need to be referencing a 'this' (the warning is trying to help you avoid unneeded null checks). Probably not applicable in your case. [see CA1822: Mark Members as Static http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245046.aspx]
2. Suppress the warning [see In Source Suppression Overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx]

HTH

Comment: I suppressed the warning since defining the method static won't work (the framework won't map the request).